# Need two dropdown lists on same form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, select

[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlE3u.png) [Result - error- trying to use two  statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB1F5.png)

I've tried for several days to succeed establishing a form that can give me two dropdown boxes where I get to select records from different tables in the same database. My goal is to be able to transfer a hotel room from one participant to the other. For that I need to be able to select the room donor first and then the recipient. I am doing this from within a cms, so I have to be able to to this selection from within the same PHP script.

As soon as I include the second  option I get problems. I do not understand how to implement the two select options on the same form. Does anyone have a solution for me? Here is my code:

---

```
    if (!isset($_POST['selected']))
    {   
        $DonorSelect = "Select * from rog_jomres_guests where property_uid in ($RallyHotels) order by surname";
        $DonorResult = mysql_query($DonorSelect) or die("Donor lookup Query failed" . mysql_error());
        $numrecords=mysql_num_rows($DonorResult); $rows = 0;
        ?>
        <html>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
        <select name="donor">
        <?php
        while ($JosRow = mysql_fetch_array($DonorResult))
        {
            $Name = $JosRow['guests_uid'] . " " . $JosRow['surname'] . "," . $JosRow['firstname'];
            $id = $JosRow['mos_userid'];
            $gid=$JosRow['guests_uid'];
            $IDName = $Name; 

            $AttendSelect = "select * from rog_sembookings where userid = $id AND semid = $ThisRally";
            $AttendResult = mysql_query($AttendSelect) or die("$ThisRally query failed" . mysql_error());
            $AttendRow = mysql_fetch_array($AttendResult);

            if ($Name == "Administrator"){ }
            elseif (!$AttendRow) { }
            else
                {
                    ?>          
                    <option value="<?php echo $gid; ?>"><?php echo $IDName;?></option>
                <?php
                }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php /**  

        <select name="transferto">
        <?php
        $RecipientSelect = "Select * from rog_users order by name";
        $RecipientResult = mysql_query($RecipientSelect) or die("Recipient lookup Query failed" . mysql_error());
        $Recipientrecords=mysql_num_rows($RecipientResult); 
        while ($RecipientRow = mysql_fetch_array($RecipientResult))
        {
            $RecipientName = $RecipientRow['name'];
            $Recipientid = $RecipientRow['id'];
            $RIDName = $RecipientName; 
            $PartSelect = "select * from rog_users where userid = $Recipientid";
            $PartResult = mysql_query($PartSelect) or die("$ThisRally PartSelect query failed" . mysql_error());
            $PartRow = mysql_fetch_array($PartResult);

            if ($RecipientName == "Administrator"){ }
            elseif (!$PartRow) { }
            else
            {
                    ?>          
                    <option value="<?php echo $Recipientid; ?>"><?php echo $RIDName;?></option>
                <?php  
            }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <?php **/ ?>

        <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $Valg; ?>" name="selected">
        </input>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php

    }       // end of clause if not set     $_POST['selected']
    else
    {       // beginning clause if set  $_POST['selected'] let's do this thing......

        if ($AdminUser==1)
            { $CurrGuest    = $_POST["donor"];}
```

---

Any help is really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Your code should fail regardless because AFAIK there is no mysql_numrows function.  You should also not be using mysql_ functions at all and should only be using prepared statements as I assume your queries include user input.  Furthermore, if you want help on this site, you're going to need to include more info about your "problems", such as an error message.

Comment: Although the function mysql_numrows is not a vital part of this script, the function exists and has helped me troubleshoot the script and db queries. I have used that function since php v5.4. I see that is is now named mysql_num_rows. However, that is a sidetrack and I should have removed it before entering the code here. I will update the article with resulting screendumps from running the script. I get no error messages. Thanks

Comment: Since mysql_ functions are no longer a part of PHP since PHP7, I'd recommend you just rewrite the code using PDO or MYSQLI with prepared statements, you may resolve your bug by just doing so.  A hint: Don't follow PHP tutorials online unless they are by a reputable source.  Noone should be recommending mysql_ functions since ~8 years ago.

Comment: Thanks Devon - I get your point. Anyone that can suggest any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['selected']))
{   
    $DonorSelect = "Select * from rog_jomres_guests where property_uid in ($RallyHotels) order by surname";
    $DonorResult = mysql_query($DonorSelect) or die("Donor lookup Query failed" . mysql_error());
    $numrecords=mysql_numrows($DonorResult); $rows = 0;
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
    <select name="donor">
    <?php
    while ($JosRow = mysql_fetch_array($DonorResult))
    {
        $Name = $JosRow['guests_uid'] . " " . $JosRow['surname'] . "," . $JosRow['firstname'];
        $id = $JosRow['mos_userid'];
        $gid=$JosRow['guests_uid'];
        $IDName = $Name; 

        $AttendSelect = "select * from rog_sembookings where userid = $id AND semid = $ThisRally";
        $AttendResult = mysql_query($AttendSelect) or die("$ThisRally query failed" . mysql_error());
        $AttendRow = mysql_fetch_array($AttendResult);

        if ($Name == "Administrator"){ }
        elseif (!$AttendRow) { }
        else
            {
                ?>          
                <option value="<?php echo $gid; ?>"><?php echo $IDName;?></option>
            <?php
            }
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <select name="transferto">
    <?php
    $RecipientSelect = "Select * from rog_users order by name";
    $RecipientResult = mysql_query($RecipientSelect) or die("Recipient lookup Query failed" . mysql_error());
    $Recipientrecords=mysql_numrows($RecipientResult); 
    while ($RecipientRow = mysql_fetch_array($RecipientResult))
    {
        $RecipientName = $RecipientRow['name'];
        $Recipientid = $RecipientRow['id'];
        $RIDName = $RecipientName; 
        $PartSelect = "select * from rog_users where userid = $Recipientid";
        $PartResult = mysql_query($PartSelect) or die("$ThisRally PartSelect query failed" . mysql_error());
        $PartRow = mysql_fetch_array($PartResult);

        if ($RecipientName == "Administrator"){ }
        elseif (!$PartRow) { }
        else
        {
                ?>          
                <option value="<?php echo $Recipientid; ?>"><?php echo $RIDName;?></option>
            <?php  
        }
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $Valg; ?>" name="selected">
    </input>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php

}       // end of clause if not set     $_POST['selected']
else
{       // beginning clause if set  $_POST['selected'] let's do this thing......

    if ($AdminUser==1)
        { $CurrGuest    = $_POST["donor"];}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. unfortunately it did not solve my challenge. Please have a look at my updated query.

Comment: Hi Rune,

From your wanted result picture I can see you have two(2) Choose buttons but you are using just one Form. When you select one option from your select element it's not necessary notify or choose that value from a button, the choose button that you are using send to a POST method the "selected" option in your select elements. If I got it, your goal is notify to the system a transfer room from you donor to your recipient or "transferto" in this case you need to update your DB with that info. What CMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks Carlos!! I am using the old joomla 1.5.26. I had a booking system that worked for years. Now I need to use this for one more year. I am not going to rewrite the entire system, that would take months and months. I just want to be able to transfer a room easily from one participant to the other. I have not been working with mods for 6 years now.

Comment: Hence, the ancient way of coding. To the details. I would like to make two selects before executing the $_post. the two variables would be donor and recipient. I will later add room selection as radio button for which room to transfer. I am uncertain about the mysqli implementation in my version of the Joomla. I think mysqli db access was from 1.6 onwards. Any idea how to approach the challenge? Thanks for your assistance here. i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the challenge myself. Some structural logical challenge. Case closed